# Can we add additional UILabels to UINavigation Bar besides its title?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am working on one app in which I have to display app's status on the UINavigation Bar. I am going to use UILabel to display the status. I was wondering whether it is possible or not ?

Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The things to do are

- create your view you want to display (subclass of `UIView`) which contains all your labels.

  - if you just want to show one single label than this first step is not needed because you can use the `UILabel` directly
- wrap your view in an `UIBarButtonItem` with the help of [`initWithCustomView:myLabelsView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- call [`setRightBarButtonItem:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/rightBarButtonItem) with your `UIBarButtonItem`-instance on `[myViewController.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myBarButtonItem animated:NO]`

Example:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    ....
    UIView *myNiceLabelView = [UILabel ...];
    UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myNiceLabelView];
    [self.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myBarButtonItem animated:NO];
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't like to see crazy user interfaces (and I don't think your users would like it either -- there isn't all that much real estate or space to work with in the navigation bar), but the technically correct answer for you here is *yes you can*:

Create a view with multiple labels (or whatever you want) embedded in it and set your `UINavigationItem`'s [`titleView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView) property to that.

Answer (score 2):

```
UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,20,200,30)];

navLabel.text = @"Your Text";
navLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:navLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function in ViewDidLoad

```
- (void) setRightNavView
```

{

// Replace titleView

```
CGRect headerTitleSubtitleFrame = CGRectMake(260, 0, 60, 44);
UIView* _headerTitleSubtitleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:headerTitleSubtitleFrame];
_headerTitleSubtitleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_headerTitleSubtitleView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;


CGRect titleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 2, 60, 20);
UILabel *titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleFrame];
titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
titleView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
titleView.text = @"Balance";
titleView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[_headerTitleSubtitleView addSubview:titleView];

CGRect subtitleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 22, 60, 22);
UILabel *subtitleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:subtitleFrame];
subtitleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
subtitleView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
subtitleView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
subtitleView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
subtitleView.text = @"sdfs";
subtitleView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[_headerTitleSubtitleView addSubview:subtitleView];

_headerTitleSubtitleView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:_headerTitleSubtitleView];
```

}

then, you can set this function at any place you want:

```
-(void) setBalanceTop:(NSString*)balance{
//NSArray *arrView = self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews;
//NSLog(@"So view con: %d", (int)arrView.count);
//NSLog(@"Desc: %@", arrView.description);
```

//Index at here depends on your Naviga Controller has how many subviews

```
if([self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:2] != nil){
    UIView* balanceView = [self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
    UILabel* titleView = [balanceView.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"Type class: %@", [titleView description]);
    if((titleView != nil) && ([titleView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]))
        titleView.text = balance;
}
```

}